# What is the meaning of "would do" here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

The text is as follows:

> Wordiness: Why use five words when one would do? Excess verbiage doesn’t make you sound smart, it just makes your writing a slog to read.

Why use five words when one would do?—this is the sentence I cannot understand.

Comment: You need to look in a dictionary for this sort of this. Not use Google. :0

Comment: Lambie, what dictionary would be the best? Please?

Comment: Well, either the Collins Dictionary, Merriam-Webster or MacMillan. If you can afford it, the Oxford English Dictionary (by subscription only). Also, it's not a bad idea to have a real dictionary on your desk. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to **do** in that sense means: *to be sufficient or to be enough*

Sample: Why use five words when one word is sufficient or enough?

For example:

We're going out for dinner. **Will 40 dollars do** or shall I bring more?